# Injecting Spring bean in a Groovy class

Tags: java, spring, groovy, spring-boot, aspectj

I am trying to autowire a spring bean into a groovy class. The groovy class itself is not instantiated by a Spring container, so I am using the @Configurable annotation to have spring autowire the bean. When I create a the groovy class(AcceptFilter) using the new operator, I can see that Spring is properly injecting the bean however when I use the following:

```
GroovyClassLoader groovyCompiler = new GroovyClassLoader();
Class clazz = groovyCompiler.parseClass(new File("src/main/groovy/filters/pre/AcceptFilter.groovy"));
AcceptFilter filter = (AcceptFilter) clazz.newInstance();
```

the injected bean in the AcceptFilter class is always null. It almost seems as if AspectJ is ignoring the @Configurable annotation when the groovy class is compiled and instantiated at runtime.

Comment: Is it possible to force `AcceptFilter` to use a predefined interface so you can set the dependency yourself on the instantiated object?

Comment: I just ended up doing that, basically I had the AcceptFilter extend a Java class and had my dependencies @Autowired there. I also had to declare set @Configurable(preConstruction=true) without which I was still seeing null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a base Java class, declared all my dependencies there and had the Groovy class extend that. I also had to change the @Configurable to use preConstruction = true